# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton Instrumentation Test

Tags: android, android-espresso

The app works fine if I normally run the app but when I try to test it shows error here is the full log of the error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
>   at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.runOnMainSync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:441)
>   at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.onActivity(ActivityScenario.java:564)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.internalLaunch(FragmentScenario.java:300)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(FragmentScenario.java:282)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(FragmentScenario.java:262)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(FragmentScenario.java:244)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.launchInContainer(FragmentScenario.java:228)
>   at com.medium.todoapp.HomeFragmentInstrumentedTest.testRecyclerView(HomeFragmentInstrumentedTest.kt:14)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   at androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
>   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
>   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
>   at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
>   at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:392)
>   at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
>   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
>   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>   at com.medium.todoapp.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.kt:16)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2169)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1992)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1818)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:297)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$1.perform(FragmentScenario.java:317)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$1.perform(FragmentScenario.java:301)
>   at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.lambda$onActivity$2$ActivityScenario(ActivityScenario.java:551)
>   at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario$$Lambda$4.run(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   at android.app.Instrumentation$SyncRunnable.run(Instrumentation.java:1950)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
>   at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
>   at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:213)
>   at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:148)
>   at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:76)
>   at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:211)
>   at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:200)
>   ... 36 more
>   Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'

Here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="adapter"
            type="com.medium.todoapp.adapters.ToDoListAdapter" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".HomeFragment">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:adapter="@{adapter}"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_todo" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Here is my TestFile

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class HomeFragmentInstrumentedTest {

    @Test
    fun testRecyclerView() {
        val homeScenario = launchInContainer(HomeFragment::class.java)
        homeScenario.onFragment {
            Assert.assertNotEquals(it.view?.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView), null)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testAddTodoButton() {
        val homeScenario = launchInContainer(HomeFragment::class.java)
        homeScenario.onFragment {
            Assert.assertNotEquals(it.view?.findViewById(R.id.addToDo), null)
        }
    }
}
```

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        bindings = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        bindings?.apply {
            this.adapter = ToDoListAdapter()
        }
        return bindings?.root
    }
```

**Build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.medium.todoapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    // AndroidX
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    // Test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // Tests
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'

    // Mockito
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.24.5"
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.24.5"

    // FragmentScenario
    debugImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72"
    debugImplementation ("androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.2.4") {
        // required, while there is no version 1.2.0 yet.
        exclude group: "androidx.test", module: "core"
    }

    // Navigation Architecture Component
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `HomeFragment.onCreateView` method?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti check update.

Comment: It seems ok. Are you using something like `getApplicationContext()` in your `Adapter`?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti no.. nothing. The app works fine but when I try to run the instrumentation test it's crashing,

Comment: What's your App Theme right now?

Comment: @DeepLathia This `parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: can see file build.gradle ???

Comment: @JavadDehban see update!

Comment: Can you change the parent theme to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" and check again if it works.

Comment: I just built this exact example in order to post a question. Thanks for doing that part for me already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to replace `launchInContainer(HomeFragment::class.java)` with:

```
launchInContainer(HomeFragment::class.java, null, R.style.AppTheme, null)
```

`R.style.AppTheme` has to inherit from `Theme.AppCompat`

Comment: It worked without inheriting from `Theme.AppCompat`. Thanks, man!

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun Your theme probably inherits from `Theme.AppCompat` indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the build.gradle file for your application.
2. Make sure that the repositories section includes Google's Maven Repository google(). For example:

   ```
     repositories {
       google()
       jcenter()
     }
   ```

3.Add the library to the dependencies section:

```
    dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
    // ...
  }
```

more info [link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md)

Comment: can you send your  code to my email address? maybe i can help you

Comment: Sure! But you don't need my code. Just copy-paste the code from my question.